# properties of measures with density

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu=\mu f$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$.
Then $f$ is $\mu$-a.e. unique and $\mu$-a.e. real.

Also: If $f(\omega)>0$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, $\mu$ is also $\sigma$-finite.

I was able to show the uniqueness, but I don't quite know how to show that $f$ is real almost everywhere. I think this has to do with the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\nu$, but I don't quite know how to work this.

Also how do I show the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ if $f(\omega)>0$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\Omega=\bigcup_nE_n$, where $E_n\in\mathcal A$ and $\nu(E_n)$ is finite, and define $F_k:=\{f\geqslant k\}$. We have 
$$\int_{E_n}f\mathrm d\mu\geqslant k\mu(E_n\cap F_k).$$
Since the LHS is finite and $E_n$ has finite measure, we have for each $n$ that $\mu(E_n\cap F_k)\to 0$ as  $k\to\infty$, hence $\mu(E_n\cap\{f= \infty\})=0$ for each $n$.

For the last part, consider $S_n:=\{(n+1)^{-1}\leqslant f\lt n^{-1}\}$.